# R Ctree Function - get error: Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'S4'

Tags: r, decision-tree

I am using the ctree function in r as follows:

`model = ctree(fmla, data=dev, ctree_control(mincriterion=0.95, minbucket=100L, maxdepth=5))`

But this returns an error:

> Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'S4'

I have tried using both factor and numberic dependent variables but still the same error.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: I believe it is something to do with the ctree_control line as if i remove it, it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the third argument to `ctree()` is `subset`, if you are using `ctree()` from the `party` package. If you were using `ctree()` from the `partykit` package, the third argument would be `weights`.

Try giving the `control` or `controls` argument (depending on the package) explicitly as in

```
ctree(fmla, data = dev, 
      control = ctree_control(mincriterion = 0.95, minbucket = 100L, maxdepth = 5))
```

(it doesn't make a difference here whether you write `control` or `controls`)